# Magnify - in the hover thumbnail gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery with thumbnails,
After I hover on thumbnail the main photo is changing to the hovered one.
But I need help with magnifying the main photo.

I tried many free magnify scripts but none of them worked well.
Always when I hovered on any other thumbnail and then again on the main photo it showed the previous one or didn't work.

*HTML*

```
<div class="imgBox"><a href="big/default1.png">
    <img src="small/default1small.png" class="zoom"/>
</a></div>

<ul class="thumb">
  <li>
    <a onclick="return false" target="imgBox" href="small/default1small.png">
      <img src="small/default1small.png"/>
    </a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a onclick="return false" target="imgBox" href="small/default2small.png">
       <img src="small/default2small.png"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*JS with JQUERY*

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.thumb a').mouseover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.imgBox img').attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    $('.imgBox a').attr("href", $(this).attr("href"));
    $('.imgBox a .magnify .magnify-lens').css("background","url('$(this)') 0px 0px no-repeat");
        }) 
    })
```

After I hover on thumbnail and again hover on the main photo I expect it to magnify properly

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgxaRX

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for [Updated code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVGyEB)